# Define $S\equiv\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid x^2<2\}$. Show that $\sup S=\sqrt{2} $.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Define $S\equiv\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid x^2<2\}$. Show that $\sup S=\sqrt{2} $.

---

For this question, I think that I would use the completeness axiom. As $3$ is greater than $2$, so $S$ has a upper bound. To yield a contradiction, I think I need to find there exists an constant $c$ which is a least upper bound such that $b^2>2$, then there exists a number $r$ such that $b-r$ also in upper bound of $S$ which gives a contradiction since $b$ is the least upper bound of $S$. Then we can end the proof.

---

Does the idea right? If not, can anyone give a suggestion or a hit to write a better proof? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: density..

Comment: The details will depend on your construction of the reals. For instance, in the Cauchy sequence construction, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ essentially for free, which makes this fairly straightforward to prove (you can argue that $S=(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ so that $\overline{S}=[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$).

Comment: Alternately, if the reals are "the unique complete linearly ordered field", then you can argue that there is a least upper bound, it cannot have $b^2<2$ (for otherwise there is a member of $S$ which is larger than it) and it cannot have $b^2>2$ (for then a smaller bound can be found by averaging the given bound and $\sqrt{2}$). This is essentially your idea. Formalizing the first part is a little bit tricky, because you can't simply argue that the average of $b$ and $\sqrt{2}$ must be in $S$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Here is an elementary argument.

If you take any $x \in S$ and a rational number $r < 1$ such that $$0 < r < (2 - x^2)/(2x  + 1)$$

show that $x + r \in S$. This shows that $S$ has no maximum element.

Consider $T = \{y \in \mathbb Q; y^2 > 2\}$ and similarly show that there is no minimum element in $T$.

**Conclusion:** If $a = \sup S$ then $a^2 = 2$, $a > 0$. Use a simple contradiction.

Comment: why $r<(2-x^2)(2x+1)$

Comment: to get $(x + r)^2  < 2$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2<x2\implies -\sqrt 2<x<\sqrt 2$, $\sqrt 2$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, and since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there is an $x\in Q$ such that $\sqrt 2-\epsilon<x<\sqrt 2$.  So $x^2<2$ implies $x\in S$, and so $\sup S=\sqrt 2$.