# Why $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}, x<\sqrt{2}\}$ has no supremum in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis

If i suppose that there exists $M=\sup\{x\in\mathbb{Q}, x<\sqrt{2}\}$ such that $M\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $M^2<2$

How to find a contradiction?

I consider $M'=\displaystyle\frac{M^2+2}{2M}\in \mathbb{Q}$ but i find that $M'>\sqrt{2}$ and $M<M'$ .

I don't find a contradiction

Comment: Try $(1/2)((M/2)+(2/M))$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's his $M'$, isn't it?

Comment: @YoT, no, I don't think so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Whoops, you're right, missing a $/2$ on the $M^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i find $M'^2-2=\frac{M^4-24M^2+16}{16M^2}$ i can't know if it is positif or negatif

Comment: To prove the statement in the title by contradiction, you need $M\in \mathbb R$ instead?

Comment: @JohnMa no i need to do two things first prove that this set has no $\sup$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ after that prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is the sup

Comment: @GerryMyerson are you there please

Comment: If you really want to have a contradiction from "there exists $M  = \sup\{x\in{\mathbb Q},x<\sqrt{2}\}$ such that $M \in \mathbb Q$ and $M^2 < 2$", that is trivial: $M = \sqrt{2}$ and therefore $M^2 = 2$, contradicting $M^2 < 2$. So, you'd better formulate carefully what it is that you want to prove.

Comment: The point of the question is to show $M = \sqrt 2$. @Magdiragdag

Comment: @JohnMa Really? Would the OP be happy with a general proof that $\sup\{x \in \mathbb{Q} ; x < a \} = a$? That's why I'm saying that the OP should formulate carefully what the question really is.

Comment: @Magdiragdag first i want to show that the set has no sup in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Vrouvrou Note that your question has been essentially answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325659/define-s-equiv-x-in-mathbbq-mid-x22-show-that-sup-s-sqrt2?rq=1). See the answer by Aaron Maroja in particular.

Comment: @Vouvrou And you would be happy with first proving that the sup is $\sqrt{2}$ and then that $\sqrt{2} \not \in {\mathbb Q}$? Or do you want to prove this without referencing the real numbers at all? In that case, it's strange to already talk about $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @JohnMa i don't understand the proof

Comment: @Magdiragdag i suppse that there exists $M=\sup\{x\in \mathbb{Q}, x^2<2\}$ abd $M\in \mathbb{Q}$ as $M$ is the sup we have that $M^2<2$  Now i want to find $M'\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $M'<M$ and this is a contradiction with the definition of $M$

Comment: His $x$ is your $M$ and he choose $M' = M + \frac{2 - x^2}{2(2x  + 1)}$. @Vrouvrou

Comment: @JohnMa and what is his M ?

Comment: and $M\in \mathbb Q$ so that $M^2 <2$. @Vrouvrou

Comment: so i must take $M'=M+\frac{2-M^2}{2(2M+1)}$ @JohnMa

Comment: Sorry, Vrouvrou, I'm not sure why I thought my $M'$ would work.

Comment: Taking the supremum with at strict inequality will not guarantee a strict inequatlity, i.e. you will only be sure that $M^2 \leq2$.

Comment: @AD. if i take $M\in \mathbb{Q}$ then it is imposible to have that $M=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Vrouvrou What I just said is general: If we have  $$ A =\sup\{x\in B: \,x<y\}$$ then we cannot conclude $A<y$.