# Prove that the supremum of the set $A = \{x \in \Bbb Q \; | x^2 < 2\}$ is $\sqrt{2}$ in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A = \{x \in \Bbb Q \; | x^2 < 2\}$.

Prove that $\sup_{x \in A}\, (x) = \sqrt{2}\;$ in real line $\Bbb R.$

I could prove the case in the rational line where no supremum exists. In $\Bbb R, $ it is easy to see that the supremum exists due to least-upper bound property (we know that 2 is an upper bound of $A$). But I don't know how to prove that supremum is equal to $\sqrt{2}\,$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you prove that $\sup \le \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Show that for $a>\sqrt 2$ (i.e., $a^2>2$ and $a>0$), you have $a>\sup A$; similar for $<$

Comment: @Wojowu I could prove that there is no supremum in rational line. But I am confused about how to approach the problem in the real line.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of supremum, and test whether $\sqrt{2}$ satisfies it? If not, at what point do you get stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define $S\equiv\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid x^2\lt2\}$. Show that $\sup S=\sqrt{2} $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325659/define-s-equiv-x-in-mathbbq-mid-x22-show-that-sup-s-sqrt2)

Comment: @Cheesecake yes i got the answer there also. I guess i should delete my question then?

Comment: If an answer to a question you posted was given, you shouldn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound on $A$, since $ x\in A$ implies $x < \sqrt{2}$. To show it is the least upper bound, suppose there were another, say $A< x' < \sqrt{2}$.  There are infinitely many rationals in $(x',\sqrt{2})$, so that there would be an element of $A$ less than $\sqrt{2}$ but greater than $x'$, which contradicts $x'$ as an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: It might be useful to mention to the OP the result you are using: the fact that rationals are *dense* in $\mathbb R$.